# How can I avoid page faults with QML when using signals to communicate with and remove dynamic items?

Tags: qt, qml

*This pertains to a QML/C++  tile-based 2d Tower Defense Style Game*

https://github.com/mikeNickaloff/TowerDefense-FullCommand-v2

### **The issue:**

I decided to simply create my own form of collision checking, which is  very efficient.. 
but it has a slight problem:

The collision checking system I wrote generates  **thousands and thousands** of  **page faults**  very quickly -- over 1 million in a couple minutes.

The collision checking is responsible for handling bullet collisions.

I was wondering if anybody could help me pick out the fundamental flaw in the design that is causing the huge spike in page faults.

## The Relevant Code

#### main.qml   [ 3 functions ]

```
  property Component attackerComponent: Qt.createComponent("src_qml/AttackerVisual.qml");

/* create a dynamic attacker   */
    function create_atttacker(i_attacker)  {
        var component;
        component = attackerComponent;
        if (component.status == Component.Ready) {

            var dynamicObject = component.createObject(background, { /* properties here  from i_attacker */ });



   /*  CONNECTIONS  FROM   DYNAMIC ATTACKER OBJECT TO MAIN.QML */
            dynamicObject.show_particles.connect(particleOverlay.customEmit);
            dynamicObject.removeAttacker.connect(removeAttacker);




        }
    }

/* remove an attacker from the game */

function removeAttacker(attackerObject) {

     /*   mark the tiles that this attacker was on now inactive
          so that guns wont continue to shoot at them */

     var current_tile = attackerObject.current;
     var target_tile = attackerObject.target;
     current_tile.isActiveTarget = false;
     current_tile.isActiveTarget = false;



    /*   disconnect the show particles signal from the particle system */

    attackerObject.show_particles.disconnect(particleOverlay.customEmit);



    /*   Remove the attacker from the game's traqcking system */

    game.board.removeAttacker(attackerObject);



    /* destroy the attacker object */

    attackerObject.destroy();



}




/*  create a new bullet that can be fired from  a Gun Item (gunObj) */

function create_projectile(gunObj, target_x, target_y) {
    var projectileComponent = 
          Qt.createComponent("src_qml/ProjectileVisual.qml");

    if (projectileComponent.status == Component.Ready) {





        var newObj = projectileComponent.createObject(background, {/* default properties from gunObj */ } );


        /* add projectile to magazine for later firing */

        gunObj.add_ammo_round(newObj);

    }
}
```

#### Projectile.qml  [ 1 animation ]

```
Item {
  ...


ParallelAnimation {
       running: true;
       id: anim1
       NumberAnimation { property: "x"; ... }
       NumberAnimation { property: "y"; ... }


       onStopped: {

          /*  send signal from target_square  that the projectile
              hit this square */
          target_square.projectile_hit(min_damage, max_damage, splash_distance);
       }
   }
```

### Here's where things start to get convoluted,
 and I suspect is the source of the page faults

---

#### Attacker.qml   [ 1 Animation,  1 Function ]

```
Item {

 id: viz


 ParallelAnimation {
        running: true;
        id: anim1
        NumberAnimation {  property: "x"; ... }
        NumberAnimation {  property: "y"; ...  }


        onStopped: {



           /* move one square forward along the attacker's path */
            current = target;
            target = next_path_square();



         /* disconnect from old path square so it doesnt send
           projectile hit events     */                    

            current.projectile_hit.disconnect(projectile_hit);
            target.projectile_hit.connect(projectile_hit);


            target.isActiveTarget = true;
            current.isActiveTarget = false;
        }
   }





 function projectile_hit(min_damage, max_damage, splash_distance) {

    /* check if Attacker hasnt been already destroyed */
    if (viz) {

        /*  send signal back to main.qml for particles */

        viz.show_particles(endX, endY);



        var attackerHealth = attacker.health;

        attackerHealth -= (Math.random() * (max_damage - min_damage)) + min_damage;

        if (attackerHealth < 1) {

                /* send signal back to main.qml   to destroy
                   this attacker */

                viz.removeAttacker(attacker);

        }

   }
```

Everything seems to work fine, but it seems to cause an infinitely increasing amount of page faults everytime a bullet hits an attacker and destroys it.

Thanks again for any advice you might have. Let me know if anything needs to be explained in better detail.. I cut out most/all of the irrelevant code already but didn't really give an in-depth explanation of how the whole process works.

Comment: I know that it won't be helpful, but the fatal flaw is that you're writing the so called "business logic" in QML/javascript. QML should only deal with presentation, js code should be short and it should not operate on the data of the application. Application's main logic should be coded in C++.

Comment: @Velkan could you please explain what is fatal to use more or less complex JavaScript code within QML file? Furthermore the javascript code used in question is not really business logic but setting some properties of QML component.
So how do you want to do this from C++ side?

Comment: Estimate how many components and items are created and destroyed. Also, note that there is no need to do `Qt.createComponent()` every time (it's probably re-parses the QML code). About application logic: for games I do a separate renderer, so QML is used only for the overlay GUI. If I had a requirement to render the whole game with QML - I would probably do all logic in C++, and then give coordinates/states of the objects via the `QAbstractListModel`s to QML. QML could render that with `ListView`s and maybe do some basic interpolation.

Comment: QML's javascript engine is not a general-purpose engine. It does its job best at evaluating bindings. Any other use is fine as long as it's done once, e.g. in setup code, or infrequently, e.g. when reacting to user input. Writing game logic in javascript is fine when you're running on a web browser with a general-purpose javascript runtime. QML doesn't have one. They ditched V8 precisely because it was way too high overhead to evaluate bindings in QML. The page faults are because the runtime goes through lots of pages, and possibly you leak memory, too (yes, JS code can leak!).

Comment: I already have most of the game written in C++, and only some of the logic is written in QML -- most of the complex stuff is actually in C++ anyways.  

I can probably migrate the rest of the logic to C++ pretty easily -- interesting to note that they don't have a general purpose Javascript parser with QML -- seems fairly counter-productive  to even have a Javascript implementation at all with QML

Comment: @Velkran  That is what the purpose of the NumberAnimations are -- they are basically acting as interpolators for the dynamically created items like bullets that are basically only going to be there for a short time and then disappear -- and rather than re-parsing the entre QML file  I actually have it set up so that each Gun has a "Clip" with 3-4  bullet items that are invisible, and they just cycle which one is made visible and then fires the animation and puts it back on top of the gun invisible when finished -- seems to work fine -- only issue is with the Attackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- it didnt really have anything to do with the fact that the Logic was written in QML, or with the files I posted in the question.

The fact was that there were too many large files to post them all up here, so I picked the top 3 parts I thought were the most likely culprits.

Apparantly in the end it was all because I had a C++ Q_INVOKABLE method which was directly bound to a property which had code involving the looped generation of a somewhat complex list being casted to QVariant --

The solution was to simply change the property acccessor  from MEMBER to READ  and then save the MEMBER separately and then just return the pre-computed value whenever QML wanted it.

This pretty much wrapped up all of the memory issues.

Thanks everyone for your input

For reference:

In  Board.cpp

```js
   class Board : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

/* bad Property at fault */

/*    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant attackers READ attackers) */


/* fixed version */
Q_PROPERTY(QVariant attackers MEMBER m_attackers)

public:
Board(QObject *parent = 0 );



/* bad declaration */
/* QVariant attackers() {
    QVariant rv;
    foreach(Attacker * attacker, this - > m_attacker_hash.values()) {
        rv.append(QVariant::fromValue(attacker));
    }
    return rv;
} */


/* Good declaration */
QVariant  m_attackers;


/*   One time population of m_attackers */
Q_INVOKABLE bool update_attackers() { 
    QVariant rv;
    foreach(Attacker * attacker, this - > m_attacker_hash.values()) {
        rv.append(QVariant::fromValue(attacker));
    }
    m_attackers = rv;
    return true;
    
    
} 
};
```